# Is it possible to change the default text color of a JComboBox when it is locked .setEnabled (false)?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to get the same result as when the `setDisabledTextColor` method is called for example. But I am not reaching the solution.

I would greatly appreciate any collaboration since I am learning Java!